# What "mean" means in JMeter metrics

Tags: jmeter, average

I'm trying to understand JMeter metrics in [JMeter Real-time results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)

```
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.minAT
Min active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.maxAT
Max active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.meanAT
Mean active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.startedT
Started threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.endedT
Finished threads
```

Is mean equal average active threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, `Mean` is taken from [apache commons math3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/Mean.html):

> Computes the arithmetic mean of a set of values. Uses the definitional formula:
>
> mean = sum(x_i) / n
>
> where n is the number of observations.

You can check [Arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) which is *simply put* an average:

> arithmetic mean (or mean or **average**)